# How to style non-Widget elements like jQuery widgets

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'd like to apply similar styling to elements like textboxs, checkboxes, etc. that my pref-fab jQuery UI theme applies to the jQuery UI widgets.  Is there a solid way to do this, or is it a mix and match process manually choosing style classes from the theme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CSS file of the UI theme is well-commented. For basic styling have a look at the `.ui-widget` and `.ui-state classes`. For checkboxes check with Firebug how the jQuery button widgets are styled. For textboxes check how the autocomplete widget is styled. It's pretty much a mix-and-match thing where you copy the classes from the theme CSS.

Answer (score 0):

always you can make you're own UI component,
the problem is you have to be very good at CSS,Javascript to do that

you can design your  widget and style them, then encapsulate them for reusing,